# Return True if Arrays have same elements

Tags: java

I could use some help comparing two arrays, previously created in another method.  They are called enterNumbers, user input array and drawNumbers, a randomly generated array.

My method header should look like this:

```
 public static boolean containSameElements(int[] enterNumbers, int[] drawNumbers)
{

}
```

The method should compare the two arrays and return true if the numbers are the same, regardless of the order.

Not looking for the answer, just maybe a place to start.

Comment: what about the numeric count?   so like, if there are 5 3's would it return true if comparing:   [3] with [3,3,3]

Comment: If you're not looking for the answer, then you'll want to at least ask a coherent specific question.

Comment: @NandkumarTekale: this will make [1, 2, 2] equal to [1, 1, 2] and to [1, 2, 3]

Comment: I would first check if the arrays are of same length and return false if not the case.  Then I would sort the arrays, iterate over one and check if int is same at same place.

Comment: @NandkumarTekale: converting them to sets doesn't change anything. The problem is still the same.

Comment: All of this information has been very helpful.  My apologies for a vague question again.  I am trying.  How can I call this method with this syntax from main?  I tried using containSameElements(enterNumbers, drawNumbers); and I get Can't find Variable.  I knew that would be the case but not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can either

1. Create two [histograms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) (using a hash based map/set) to count elements
   in each array, and then compare the sets/maps. This solution is `O(n)`
   space and `O(n)` time *on average*. Have a look at [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) or [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) for this. (Either you want Map or Set depends if existence of duplicates is important or not)
2. Another solution is sort and iterate. This is `O(nlogn)` time worst
   case. Have a look on [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29) for this solution.

Comment: You can't use sets because that doesn't account for duplicates.

Comment: @arshajii Well it depends if it is important or not - the question is ambigious regarding this aspect.

Comment: Instead, `Map<number, occurences>` would meet this need.

Comment: if it is something like a lotery, you won't get the same int twice, but true the OP doesn't mention that !!

Answer (score 1):

Just sort them before

```
  Arrays.sort(enterNumbers);
  Arrays.sort(drawNumbers);

  if(Arrays.equals(enterNumbers, drawNumbers)){
            System.out.println("both are same");
    }
```

Comment: I dislike this answer because: `Not looking for the answer, just maybe a place to start.`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (drawNumbers.length != enterNumbers.length)
    return false;
List<Integer> base = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (Integer i : drawNumbers)
    base.add(i);
for (Integer i : enterNumbers)
    base.remove(i);

return base.isEmpty();
```

Comment: This is as inefficient solution as it gets, with `O(n^2)` average case time complexity and `O(n)` space complexity.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common "problem" which can be solved using different methods. If I understand you correctly, all of the numbers have be inside the both arrays, but they don't have to be at the same indexes?

Then you can just make a while/for loop with (with two counters; one for each array) and check if the number on index 0 in the first array equals any of the numbers in the second array. If it doesn't the while/for-loop is done and the test failed. If it *does* go on to the next index in the first array. Continue until everything is tested(all numbers in first array versus the second array) or until a number doesn't exist in both arrays. Good luck

Comment: THANK YOU!  This really helps me, I'm going to go try at it.